# Mysql change default value of the column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database v 8.0.16 and I need to create a new table like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE /*prefix*/attachments_backup SELECT * FROM /*prefix*/attachments;
```

Also the table 'attachments' has a field 'date_added' and when I tried to copy data from one table to another I got 'Invalid default value for date_added'. So I want to change the default value of 'date_added' in the new table(not in old) and I think it will help me.

How can I do this?

## Updates

Attachments table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI5qR.png)

Comment: Please add table definition and sample data as is question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have already done)

Comment: Please add table definition.(ie what is the default in attachments for date added?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
**First: Create the Empty Table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE attachments_backup LIKE attachments;
```

**Second: Copy Data into Table**

```sql
INSERT attachments_backup SELECT * FROM attachments;
```